# Can't join rabbitMQ cluster: Error: nodedown

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing

I am new to rabbitMQ and Linux.
I am following clustering guide at 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

I have three nodes all running CentOS 7 (On virtual machines with statics IPs).

I have copied the erlang cookie to all machines.

I have set hosts in hosts file as the following
This on machine 2

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4   localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.198.100   rabbit1
127.0.0.1 rabbit2
192.168.198.102   rabbit3
```

But hen trying to join rabbit2 to rabbit1 using

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1
```

I get the following error

```
Clustering node rabbit@localhost with rabbit@rabbit1 ...
Error: unable to connect to nodes [rabbit@rabbit1]: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@rabbit1]

rabbit@rabbit1:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit1
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
  * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-72@localhost'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: YlXmRhqgpV9H7lgqXslI1g==
```

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this?

Comment: can you ping `rabbit1` from `rabbit2`?

Comment: @DavinTryon: Yes I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nodes are named `rabbit@localhost`:

```
Clustering node rabbit@localhost with rabbit@rabbit1
```

You need to verify what the `hostname` command returns. For clustering to work, it must return eg. `rabbit1`. If it returns `localhost`, verify the configuration of your hosts. How to do that depends on the distribution.

On the Debian and Fedora VMs I have here, the hostname is configured in `/etc/hostname`. So you would need something like:

```
echo rabbit1 > /etc/hostname
```

But please refer to your distribution documentation and tools first.

Comment: Thank you. Changing hostname (localhost) to rabbitX on each machine solved the problem.

Comment: But could you explain what is cluster_name I see it is set to rabbit@rabbit2 on all nodes. why?

Comment: RabbitMQ arbitrary picks the first member of the cluster as the cluster name. You can change it to whatever you prefer with `rabbitmqctl set_cluster_name $new_cluster_name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have set 192.168.198.102 to your rabbit2 VM, so you could try and change the line in /etc/hosts from
`127.0.0.1 rabbit2` to `192.168.198.102 rabbit2`.

Also a tip, try using docker instead of VMs, it's faster and lighter.